# Sql creating a query which divides a row into multiple groups

Tags: sql, insert

I am fairly new to sql and i have a slight problem. so i have this table "main.person" which has the values 'Balance' and 'birthYear' in it.
now i want to generate statistics which shows the total balance of 3 different birthYear groups . so for example from Minimum of birthYear(oldest) to 1/3rd of the range. then from 1/3rd of the range to 2/3rd. then from 2/3 to the youngest(max value)

I've been trying to do this with ntile but it doesn't to be working quite well,because it doesn't group the range into 3 groups quite well since for example year 1958 is the same group which is 1 but also in group 2. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

this is my code:

```
create or alter procedure main.generateStatistics
as
begin
declare @bracket table(
balance numeric(9,2) not null,
bracket nvarchar(20))

insert into @bracket([balance],[bracket])
SELECT balance, NTILE(3) OVER(ORDER BY birthYear) from main.person p) as z



set @group1 = (select sum(balance) from @bracket
where bracket = 1)


set @group2 = (select sum(balance) from @bracket
where bracket = 2)

set @group3 = (select sum(balance) from @bracket
where bracket = 3)

insert into main.[stats](dateCollected,totalPeople,bracket1,bracket2,bracket3)
values(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),(select count(*) from main.person), @group1, @group2,@group3)
end;
```

---

example of how i want my grouping to be

```
set @group1=(
select sum(balance) from main.person p
where birthYear <= 1959)

set @group2=(
select sum(balance) from main.person p
where birthYear >= 1960 and birthYear <= 1979)

set @group3=(
select sum(balance) from main.person p
where birthYear >= 1980)
```

[[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get there using the NTILE analytic function, it just takes an extra step to ensure only one bucket per birthyear:

```
with bucket(grp, birthyear) as (
  select ntile(3) over (order by birthyear) grp
       , birthyear
    from (select distinct birthyear from person) x
)
select grp
     , min(p.birthyear) minyear
     , max(p.birthyear) maxyear
     , sum(balance) bal
  from person p
  join bucket b
    on b.birthyear = p.birthyear
 group by grp
```

Each group will contain almost the same number of birthyears (±1) without any birhtyears being split between buckets.

Below is a version using a temporary table similar to what was being done in the original request.

```
declare @bucket (grp int, birthyear int);

insert into @bucket(grp, birthyear) 
  select ntile(3) over (order by birthyear) grp
       , birthyear
    from (select distinct birthyear from person) x;

select @group1 = sum(balance) bal
  from person p
  join bucket b
    on b.birthyear = p.birthyear
 where grp = 1;

select @group2 = sum(balance) bal
  from person p
  join bucket b
    on b.birthyear = p.birthyear
 where grp = 2;

select @group3 = sum(balance) bal
  from person p
  join bucket b
    on b.birthyear = p.birthyear
 where grp = 3;
```

You can then finish up with your insert statement.

Comment: do you declare bucket as a table?

Comment: No, I just used a Common Table Expression (the WITH clause). I could have written it as an inline query as I did within the bucket query to get the distinct birthyears where the in line query is named x, but for more complex queries I find CTEs more legible.

Comment: since i have to do it in a procedure CTE's won't work in what other alternative can i do it?

Comment: With statements **can** be used in stored procedures, but if you really wish to avoid the CTE I'll add a version that uses temp tables.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, you can use `percentile_cont()` or `percentile_disc()`:

```
select (case when birthyear <= percentile_cont(0.333) within group (order by birthyear) over ()
             then 1
             when birthyear <= percentile_cont(0.667) within group (order by birthyear) over ()
             then 2
             else 3
        end)
```

Do note that your bins could significantly differ in size.

Comment: the code gave me an error 'percentile_cont must have a within group clause' so i arranged it to this: but it is grouping every row into 1 only

Comment: select birthYear, case when birthYear <= percentile_disc(0.333) within group (order by birthYear) over (partition by birthYear)
             then 1
             when birthYear <= percentile_disc(0.667) within group (order by birthYear) over (partition by birthYear)
             then 2
             else 3
        end
  from main.person